# Component with multple API calls in useEffect does not rerender on each resolved promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await

I'm playing around with a note taking web app and I'm having problems rendering the notes that are sent from the backend. To practice writing asynchronous code I implemented the app to ask the backend for a list of ids, one for each note file (). After the list is filled the idea is to make an API call for every element in the list, so notes can be rendered once they have loaded.

This is the main component

```
export const Notes = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState<Note[]>([]);
  const [pageIsLoading, setPageIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const noteIdsResponse = useNoteIds();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchNotes(noteIds: NoteIds) {
      try {
        noteIds.forEach(async id => {
          return fetch("http://localhost:5086/api/notes/get/" + id)
          .then(reponse => reponse.json())
          .then(data => Note.parse(data))
          .then(note =>{ 
            setNotes([...notes, note])
          })
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    if(noteIdsResponse.data) {
      fetchNotes(noteIdsResponse.data)
    }
  }, [noteIdsResponse.data])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(noteIdsResponse.loading) {
      setPageIsLoading(true);
    } else {
      setPageIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [noteIdsResponse.loading])

  return(
    <>
      <h2>Some kind of note taking system</h2>
      <Group Sx={{gap: "10px", marginBottom: "16px"}}>
        <Button>
          <Group gap={5}>
            Add
            <IconPlus/>
          </Group>
        </Button>
        <Button>Save All</Button>

        {pageIsLoading &&
          <div className="lds-ring"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
        }
      </Group>
      {noteIdsResponse.error && 
        <Group gap={20}>
          There was an error fetching the notes
          <Button onClick={() => noteIdsResponse.refetch()}>
            Retry
          </Button>
        </Group>}
      
      <Group gap={20}>
        {}
        {notes.map((note, i) => <NoteArea key={i} note={note}/>)}
      </Group>
    </>
  )
}
```

I replicated the issue in a smaller component without dependencies

```
export const NotesTest = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState<Note[]>([]);
  const didMount = useRef(false);
  const noteIds = [1, 2, 3]

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchNotes(noteIds: number[]) {
      try {
        noteIds.forEach(async id => {
          return fetch("http://localhost:5086/api/notes/get/" + id)
          .then(reponse => reponse.json())
          .then(data =>{ 
            setNotes([...notes, data])
            console.log(data)
          })
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    if(!didMount.current) {
      fetchNotes(noteIds)
      didMount.current = true;
    }
  }, [])

  return(
    <>
      {notes.map((note, i) => {
        return(
          <div key={i}>
            <h1>{note.title}</h1>
            <p>{note.content}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

And the note type

```
type Note = {
  title: string,
  content: string,
  dateTime: Date,
  id: number,
}
```

All three promises return a valid result. I confirmed this with the print to the console right after the setNotes call. However, only the first result is rendered.

I managed to render all notes using Promise.all() inside of the try block, but as the notes are only rendered when all promises have resolved it kind of defeats the purpose of what im trying to achieve.

```
Promise.all(noteIds.map(async id => {
  return fetch("http://localhost:5086/api/notes/get/" + id)
    .then(reponse => reponse.json())
    .then(data => Note.parse(data))
})).then((newNotes: Note[])=> setNotes([...notes, ...newNotes]))
```

Comment: The issue may be on this line `setNotes([...notes, data])`, but needs verifying. So I suggest you try this: `setNotes((notes) => ([ ...notes, data ]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Max Lysenko for providing a fix.
Using `setNotes(notes => ([...notes, note]))` instead of `setNotes([...notes, note])`.

My explanation of the issue is that react does not update the state until the end of the effect, so everytime `setNotes()` is called `notes` is empty. I gather that react stores the current value, which will be used to update the state and this can be accessed by using `useState` with a paramter.

If my understanding is wrong or incomplete I'd appreciate an update.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**

As @MaxLysenko said, `setNotes((notes) => ([ ...notes, data ]))` and not `setNotes([...notes, data])`.

---

**Why does it work**

The initial value of `notes` is []. Since [state variable’s value never changes within a render](https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot), and since you only run the useEffect once (because of the `didMount` ref), you can mentally replace `setNotes([...notes, data])` with `setNotes([...[], data])`. This is why the result is an array with one note. Using the updater syntax uses the last `notes` value.